# Splash screen not displaying in android

Tags: android, splash-screen

When i run the app, SplashScreen blinks for a fraction of second on the screen and disappears completely for 3 seconds. After completing 3 sec MainActivity launches. Question is how to display my splash screen with out disapearing?

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class));

        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    SplashScreen.this.finish();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    SplashScreen.this.finish();
    super.onBackPressed();
}}
```

MANIFEST FILE

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name="com.simbotix.guardianonthego.SplashScreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.simbotix.guardianonthego.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class));

        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    SplashScreen.this.finish();
```

to

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
             startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class));
              SplashScreen.this.finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
```

Also no need to finish Activity in `onBackPressed`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    SplashScreen.this.finish(); // Remove this
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Why should i remove can you please explain {SplashScreen.this.finish(); // Remove this}

Comment: When you back press, the activity automatically finish itself and `onDestroy` method get called.

Comment: Ok should i include onDestroy method in SplashScreen.java?

Comment: You can. but not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

```
       new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {    
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class));
            SplashScreen.this.finish();

        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
```

SplashScreen.this.finish(); line of code finish your SplashActivity  and you need to execute this after 3 seconds that's why it is in handler thread and executed after 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Simply just do not finish your `SplashScreen` before starting `MainActivity`.
Just remove the `SplashScreen.this.finish();` line from your `SplashScreen` class.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish()
            }
 }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
```

Instead of

```
public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class));

        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    SplashScreen.this.finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick Fix :

remove

```
SplashScreen.this.finish();
```

Change like,

```
public void run() {
        startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
```